# WordPress Logout Only If User Click Logout or If User Delete Browser History

Tags: security

This is the main requirements of my project.

After a user login, logout should be done only if user click logout button or if user delete browser history.

When browser closing, then machine restarting, changing IP address **should NOT logout the User**.

Is this possible with WordPress? Is there any filter, action hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `auth_cookie_expiration` filter to change the expiration time of the cookie WordPress sets to remember you. The user won't be logged out unless they change browser or clear their cookies (normally part of clearing history).

The problem is that you can't set a cookie to never expire, so you have to set a date in the far future. The furthest you can go is 19th January 2038, because of the [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

The value of the `auth_cookie_expiration` filter is added to `time()` so if you want to set the longest possible time for the cookie, you need to get the maximum value (`2147483647` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22479460/2684861)) and subtract `time()`:

```
function wpse_287104_cookie_expiration( $length ) {
    return time() - 2147483647;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'wpse_287104_cookie_expiration' );
```

Comment: Do you know that what is the default expiration time of WP. Just google search didn't give a answer for me....

Comment: 14 days if "Remember Me" is checked, otherwise 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in wordpress functions.php, to auto logout customer/user after payment in woocommerce or close the browser

```
function logged_in( $expirein ) {
   return 6; // 6 in seconds
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'logged_in' );

function wp_logout2() {
    wp_destroy_current_session();
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();

    /**
     * Fires after a user is logged-out.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_logout2' );
}

function wpse108399_change_cookie_logout( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ){
    if( $remember && user_can( $user_id, 'administrator' ) ){
        $expiration = 604800;// yes, I know this is 1 minute
    }
    if( $remember && user_can( $user_id, 'editor' ) ){
        $expiration = 604800;// yes, I know this is 1 minute
    }
    }
    return $expiration;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration','wpse108399_change_cookie_logout', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Bypass logout confirmation.
 */
function iconic_bypass_logout_confirmation() {
    global $wp;

    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['customer-logout'] ) ) {
            wp_redirect( str_replace( '&amp;', '&', wp_logout_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'iconic_bypass_logout_confirmation' );
```

A part of this code it's for increase expiration time to administrators of wordpress or other kinds of user

```
function wpse108399_change_cookie_logout( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ){
    if( $remember && user_can( $user_id, 'administrator' ) ){
        $expiration = 604800;// yes, I know this is 1 minute
    }
    if( $remember && user_can( $user_id, 'editor' ) ){
        $expiration = 604800;// yes, I know this is 1 minute
    }
    }
    return $expiration;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration','wpse108399_change_cookie_logout', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try setting cookies when a user logs in using `wp_set_auth_cookie`.

Something like :

```
add_action( 'wp_login', function($login, $user){
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, TRUE);
}, 10, 2 );
```

Note: Code is not tested or tried. Please check for errors.

Comment: If they're logging in the cookie's going to be set anyway, and this cookie would expire like normal. So I don't see how this helps?

Comment: Second parameter is `$remember`. Which is set to false by default. So just change it to true and let WP handle remembering users. @JacobPeattie

Comment: `$remember` is just setting the expiration to 14 days instead of 2. See [the code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_auth_cookie/).